# yarn and npm ignore scoped private registry setting

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

I am using the [Google Artifact registry](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs) for private node modules. The private modules have the scope "@myscope" and this is, what I have in my .npmrc:

```
@myscope:registry=https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/
//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:_password="eW..E="
//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:username=oauth2accesstoken
//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:email=not.valid@email.com
//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:always-auth=true
```

I have a project "test" with a dependency "@myscope/testdependency", this is the package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@myscope/testdependency": "^1.2.5"
  }
}
```

When I run a `yarn install --verbose`, I see this:

```
...
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.23567398 Performing "GET" request to "https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/@myscope%2ftestdependency".
verbose 0.381522173 Request "https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/@myscope%2ftestdependency" finished with status code 200.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
verbose 0.406426655 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope/testdependency/-/@myscope/testdependency-1.2.5.tgz".
verbose 0.86999269 Error: https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope/testdependency/-/@myscope/testdependency-1.2.5.tgz: Request failed "404 Not Found"
...
```

So the resolving part looks correct, but the actual fetching ignores my setting.

This is my yarn config:

```
info yarn config
{
  'version-tag-prefix': 'v',
  'version-git-tag': true,
  'version-commit-hooks': true,
  'version-git-sign': false,
  'version-git-message': 'v%s',
  'init-version': '1.0.0',
  'init-license': 'MIT',
  'save-prefix': '^',
  'bin-links': true,
  'ignore-scripts': false,
  'ignore-optional': false,
  registry: 'https://registry.yarnpkg.com',
  'strict-ssl': true,
  'user-agent': 'yarn/1.22.17 npm/? node/v12.16.3 linux x64',
  '@myscope:registry': 'https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/',
  lastUpdateCheck: 1645016355470
}
info npm config
{
  '@myscope:registry': 'https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/',
  '//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:_password': 'eW...E=',
  '//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:username': 'oauth2accesstoken',
  '//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:email': 'not.valid@email.com',
  '//europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/:always-auth': true
}
```

What is even more strange is that npm is also trying to get this package from the yarn registry. This is the output of `npm install --verbose`

```
...
npm http fetch GET 200 https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/@myscope%2ftestdependency 156ms
npm http fetch GET 404 https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope/testdependency/-/@myscope/testdependency-1.2.5.tgz 319ms
npm http fetch GET 404 https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope/testdependency/-/@myscope/testdependency-1.2.5.tgz 244ms
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 773ms
npm verb stack Error: 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@myscope/testdependency/-/@myscope/testdependency-1.2.5.tgz
...
```

Similar situation. There is a successful request to the private registry, but then it tries fetching it from the yarn registry.

This is the output of `npm config ls -l | grep registry`:

```
metrics-registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
@myscope:registry = "https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/"
; metrics-registry = null (overridden)
registry = "https://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

We also tried it on a machine of a colleague. Same result.

yarn version: 1.22.17
npm version: 6.14.4

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

**Update:** I tried the npmjs registry instead of Google Artifact and it is working fine with it. So it is most likely a problem related to Google

Comment: Just an assumption. The first request `https://europe-west3-npm.pkg.dev/my-project/frontend/@myscope%2ftestdependency` seems to acknowledge that the registry entry for `testdependency` exist (code 200). However it seems that besides the entry there is no actual artifact deployed hence the fallback download on the yarn package registry. There it can't find the package since it's a private dependecy/library I guess. Try to figure out if there is an existing package at the expected registry entry

Comment: It is there. There are even install instructions for this package saying this (for npm):

npm install @pmt/testdependency@1.2.5

And when I execute it, I get the described error